# How do I use plugins in the vim-scripts package?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What is the correct way to include the plugins that are part of the vim-scripts package? Nothing from the vim-scripts folder seems to be included automatically. 
Plugins in `/usr/share/vim/vim73` are available, plugins in `/usr/share/vim-scripts` are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install vim-scripts, vim-addon-manager gets installed as a dependency. You can use `vam` to enable plugins.

Comment: I'm on precise server btw. Interestingly enough, vim-addon-manager is only a "recommendation" and the command is `vim-addons` on my system. `sudo vim-addons -w install detectindent` installed it to /var/lib/vim/addons (`-w` for system-wide install, otherwise it ends up in the current user's home directory). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that changed between precise and quantal then :)