# How to properly use `vim-airline` package

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

After installation of the `vim-airline` and `vim-airline-themes` packages, what is the best way to use / activate them?

I can manually copy the `.vim`-files over, but this defeats the purpose of package management with eventual updates. Using vim 8, so I think the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216818/how-do-i-use-plugins-in-the-vim-scripts-package) is outdated for the new vim 8 package management.

Comment: It's not outdated. It still uses vim-addon-manager. Check the package README and dependencies.

Comment: @muru: I should have tried before assuming that the new vim 8 doesn't need `vam`, but thanks for the heads-up and your original answer.